# Adding different filters to different antMachers in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to enable WebSecurity in spring. I actually have two endpoints, (one GET and one POST) and I would like to use a different `GenericFilterBean` for each request.

I have tried the code below, but I am not able to get the desired behaviour. With every request (GET and POST), both filters (GetUserIdByToken and AuthUserIdTransactionId) are invoked. Could you guys provide me with one solution? One and just one filter with every request. Thanks in advance.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()       
        .requestMatchers()
           .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/me/accounts/{accountId}/transactions")
           .and()
           .addFilterBefore(new GetUserIdByToken(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/me/accounts/{accountId/transactions/{transactionId}")
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new AuthUserIdTransactionId(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're configuring `HttpSecurity`, you're configuring what will end up in the `FilterChain`. This means that **every** filter you add to `HttpSecurity` will be invoked if the filter chain is invoked.

#### Method 1

If you want to selectively "turn off" certain filters in the `FilterChain`, you could configure them to do so:

```
public class GetUserIdByToken extends GenericFilterBean {
    private AntPathRequestMatcher requestMatcher;

    public GetUserIdByToken(String path, HttpMethod method) {
        this.requestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher(path, method);
    }

    // ...
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
       throws IOException, ServletException {
        
       if(!this.requestMatcher.matches(req) {
           chain.doFilter(req,resp);
           return;
       }

       // filter logic goes here...
    }
}
```

You could do the same to `AuthUserIdTransactionId`. Then it would just be a matter of passing the appropriate paths and http methods to each constructor, and adding both filters to `HttpSecurity`.

#### Method 2

If, on the other hand, you want a completely separate `FilterChain`, you must configure two `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`s. This [blog post](http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2017/08/spring-security.html) explains how to do it pretty well. Or you could checkout the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity).